# Is it possible to use a DynamicResource in a MultiBinding at all?

Tags: wpf, multibinding, markup-extensions, dynamicresource

In this case I am looking to use strings declared in a resource dictionary as part of a binding on a `Text` property. Binding just a single dynamic resource string is not a problem:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource keyToMyString}" />
```

But you quickly run into problems if you need to use a [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) on a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) because you need to insert dynamic text or want to combine several strings. For example, if my MultiBinding looks like this:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} some more text">
        <Binding Source="{x:Static Resources:Strings.string1}" />
        <Binding Source="{x:Static Resources:Strings.string2}" />
    </MultiBinding>
<TextBlock.Text>
```

I can inject `string1` and `string2` from the specified resource file into the bound text, no problems there. But I cannot find a way to use strings from a dynamic resource in the same way. (I'm using this method to inject company and product names into text from a merged resource dictionary).

With a [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) I can circumvent this issue by using several [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) items for the TextBlock content ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918689/109702)):

```
<TextBlock >
    <Run Text="{DynamicResource CompanyName}" />
    <Run Text="{DynamicResource ProductName}" />
    <Run Text="{DynamicResource MajorVersion}" />
</TextBlock>
```

but this is of no help when needing to bind the dynamic resource to the [Window Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.title.aspx) property. Is there anyway to accomplish this with (creative, if necessary) use of the existing markup extensions (like `x:Static`, etc)? Or do we have to write our own markup extension to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805351/use-ivalueconverter-with-dynamicresource.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932736/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-dynamicresource-of-clrstring-to-another-source-instead

Comment: Just a note: while both of the suggested duplicates are interesting in their own right, they should be considered slightly related rather than duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> Dynamic resource references have some notable restrictions. At least one of the following must be true:
>
> - The property being set must be a property on a `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`. That property must be backed by a `DependencyProperty`.
> - The reference is for a value within a `Style` `Setter`.
> - The property being set must be a property on a `Freezable` that is provided as a value of either a `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement` property, or a `Setter` value.

[Source: XAML Resources, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So, in case of using the `Binding`, all the statements are violated.

As was shown, the `DynamicResourceExtension` works just fine for an instance of the `Run` class because the `Run` class (at least) is derived from the `FrameworkContentElement` class.

### Additional references

1. Resources section: [Wha' Happened Part Two: More Property Changes in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/03/21/wha-happened-part-two-more-property-changes-in-wpf.aspx).
2. [WPF: Dependency Properties & Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988797/wpf-dependency-properties-resources).