# Is it possible to bind a DynamicResource of clr:string to another source instead of literal?

Tags: wpf, string, xaml, data-binding, dynamicresource

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.WPF_Application.ResourceSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="centralRes">Hello, world!</sys:String>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBox Name="src" />
        <TextBlock Name="dst" Text="{DynamicResource centralRes}" FontSize="56" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I am just learning, and was curious if I can bind the `string` literal in `centralRes` to another control's Text property (like `src.Text`), so when it updates, all things bound to it like `dst` automatically update.

Almost like a central hub for a piece of info. Is this possible to do?

Example of what I want:

```
<sys:String x:Key="centralRes" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=src}">Hello, world!</sys:String>
```

Comment: I used `<sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>` throughout my application and had no problem with it.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I need a way of binding that `True` or literal value in case of a string to another source, in XAML. I know if I change it in code it would all work magically.

Comment: So you need it to be dependent on like a `MainViewModel` and display the same information throughout the app? Obviously only the Items that are bound to that Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Binding directly to the object (saved in Resources) in this case is not easy if not wanting to say it's impossible. However you can bind the `Text` to the `Window` and set the `Path` to that resource and it works OK:

```
<TextBox Name="src" 
         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
         Path=Resources[centralRes],Mode=OneWayToSource,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**More about binding directly to the object:** When doing like this, the `Source` of the `Binding` will be assigned to a `StaticResource` and the `Path` should be `.` (otherwise an error saying 2 way binding requires Path or XPath although we set Mode to BindingMode.OneWayToSource). Using `DynamicResource` is not possible for a `Binding`'s Source. After that the code *compiles* OK but the Binding does nothing. I doubt that the `StaticResource` is the problem, however as I said, `DynamicResource` cannot be used. Hence we're stuck at binding directly to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Use StaticResource instead ie. {StaticResource centralRes}